# How to get Huawei Product ID without stock ROM?

Tags: bootloader, huawei, sim-unlocking

I have Lineage as opposed to the stock ROM, so putting:

```
*#*#1357946#*#*
```

does not work for me.

Recommended on alternate posts were downloading a program called "Huawei Product ID Generator", but this does not work for me as my device model is not an option listed (my device model is KIW-L24).

And this generator (http://www.rootjunkysdl.com/files/) does not have my phone listed either.

Do any of you know how I can get my Product ID since these three methods do not work for me?

Thank you!